# How to count Product ‘A-D’ without Null Value?

Tags: qlikview

When I was trying to create a dashboard in Qlikview, I write a statement to show up the following product data in a bar chat:

[image]

As you can see in the pic, however, the is a null value product to be counted.
I write the following statement in the Expression of Qlikview BarChart:

```
Count({<PRODUCT={'Enoxaparin Sodium','Insulin Glargine 300','Non-Promotional','Sevelamer Carbonate'}>}DISTINCT CALLID).
```

It can display what I want to see, but some other product may be missing in the future counting.
Who can tell me how to write an expression to count all the product without couting Null Value in Product Field?
I input like this `Count({<PRODUCT={'<>NULL'}>}DISTINCT CALLID)`, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this problem by doing this:

```
count(distinct if(Not IsNull(PRODUCT),CallId))
```

Comment: Sometimes when you have a very complex data model the IF() can give you some unexpected answers, so another way of removing that null is the "Suppress when null" tick box on the dimension tab of the chart properties